# Saving two ints into one

Tags: java, integer, hex, bitwise-operators

The saving of two ints into one int is specified as following:

> The bottom byte contains how many sectors the chunk uses. The other 3
>   bytes are containing the offset to the chunk-sector.

So if I want to extract my two numbers I have to do

```
int usedSectors  = num & 0xFF;
int sectorOffset = num >> 8;
```

But how can I save two ints into that one int e.g. I have usedSectors and sectorOffset given (we assume that usedSectors only have a range of 1 byte from 0 to 255 and sectorOffset of 3 bytes from 0 to 16777215)?

Comment: You have just given an example of " how can [you] save two ints into that one int "  so what is your doubt?  Is it that you have these instructions but you don't understand them?

Comment: I tried the following but if sectorOffset > 256 I got a problem.
   byte[] header = new byte[4];
   header[3] = sectorsAsByte[3];
   header[2] = offsetAsByte[3];
   header[1] = sectorsAsByte[2];
   header[0] = sectorsAsByte[1];

Comment: Shouldn't it be `num >>> 8`? Otherwise you get a negative sector offset sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aggrigaated_int=0;    
aggrigaated_int+=first_num;
aggrigaated_int+=second_num <<8;
```

Comment: Or `(second_num << 8) | first_num`

Answer (score 4):

Test Program:

```
public class ByteTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int expectedUsedSectors = 4;
      int expectedSectorOffset = 20000;

      int num = expectedSectorOffset;
      num = num << 8;
      num |= expectedUsedSectors;

      int usedSectors  = num & 0xFF;
      int sectorOffset = num >> 8;

      System.out.println("used sectors expected == actual? " + (expectedUsedSectors == usedSectors));
      System.out.println("offset expected == actual? " + (expectedSectorOffset == sectorOffset));
    }
}
```

First I set the 3 byte value then shift 8 bits and then set the second number.